# Why chrome can't remember previous session with puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm actually trying to use puppeteer for scraping and I need to use my current chrome to keep all my credentials. However, chrome can't remember previous session and I have to click the login button every time. By contrast, chrome can remember the saved credential. Is there a way to make it?

I'm actually using: 
Node v12.16.1 
chrome 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
puppeteer-core 2.1.0 // see: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.0/docs/api.md

test.js:

```
const pptr = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
  const browser = await pptr.launch({
    executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',//path to your chrome
    headless: false,
    args:[
                '--user-data-dir=D:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data2',
        ]
    });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://hostloc.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
  await page.waitFor(10000);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: you should use cookies so that you can get the previous data from them.

Comment: is it by design that puppeteer won't restore the previous sessions but only the 'environment' including saved credentials?

Comment: I believe yes..

Comment: Thanks a lot. I misunderstood the way puppeteer works. By the way, should I 'goto' the site twice to login in? The first for set cookies, and the second for refreshing result?

Comment: let me post an answer under your question with an example about how to set cookies, so that can be more helpful

Answer (score 3):

You should use cookies so that you can get the previous data from them. Here is a [link](https://github.com/checkly/puppeteer-examples#set-cookie) about the set cookie in the puppeteer.

Here below is an example of code for how to set cookies in puppeteer. It Sets the "login_email" property in a Paypal cookie so the login screen is pre-filled with an email address.

```
const cookie = {
  name: 'login_email',
  value: 'set_by_cookie@domain.com',
  domain: '.paypal.com',
  url: 'https://www.paypal.com/',
  path: '/',
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true
}

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setCookie(cookie)
  await page.goto('https://www.paypal.com/signin')
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'paypal_login.png' })
  await browser.close()
})()
```

Regarding get the cookies, You can create a [Chrome DevTools Protocol session](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession) on the page target using [target.createCDPSession()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#targetcreatecdpsession). Then you can send [Network.getAllCookies](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#method-getAllCookies) to obtain a list of all browser cookies.

The [page.cookies()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagecookiesurls) function will only return cookies for the current URL. So we can filter out the current page cookies from all of the browser cookies to obtain a list of third-party cookies only.

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
const all_browser_cookies = (await client.send('Network.getAllCookies')).cookies;
const current_url_cookies = await page.cookies();
const third_party_cookies = all_browser_cookies.filter(cookie => cookie.domain !== current_url_cookies[0].domain);

console.log(all_browser_cookies); // All Browser Cookies
console.log(current_url_cookies); // Current URL Cookies
console.log(third_party_cookies); // Third-Party Cookies
```

For example, get all of the cookies

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com', {waitUntil : 'networkidle2' });

  // Here we can get all of the cookies
  console.log(await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies'));

})();
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Well, how can I get the cookies from the previous saved environment? If I manually open chrome, the session is restored.

Comment: yes, but the page.cookies() call only gets cookies that are available to JavaScript applications inside the browser, I have updated my answer, I hope this will help you.

Comment: @BoWang Please let me know if you have any further query

Comment: I have tasted the example code provided by you, and I have get through this problem in mind. Thank you for your valuable advice, I really appreciate it.

Comment: After careful test, it is found that this 'Network.getAllCookies' only works fine in headful mode rather than headless mode. The latter only gives []. Is there a way works in both the two modes?

Comment: I have a web page for  puppeteer args at [!this link](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)